# Clear a FireMonkey TListView

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

Is there a preferred way to clear a TListView control or do we just cycle through all items deleting them?

Below is code to clear a TListBox. Is there something similar for TListView that I'm just missing in my searching?

```
Form1->ListBox2->Clear();
```

thanks,
russ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Items->Clear()` method:

```
ListView1->Items->Clear();
```